# How to display all digits from a bigz/bigq number using gmp package

Tags: r, gmp

How can I print all digits of 1/31 ?

```r
a = gmp::as.bigz(1) 
b = gmp::as.bigz(31)
print(a/b)

R.4.3.1 > print(a/b)
Big Rational ('bigq') :
[1] 1/31
```

I was expecting something like:

```r
"0.032258064516129032258064516129032258064516129032258064516129..."
```

Answer (score 4):

Clearly you can't print *all* of the digits of an infinitely repeating decimal ... `gmp` doesn't support arbitrary-precision floats, just integers and rationals. Here is one way using `Rmpfr` to get a decimal representation ... (you can pick `precBits` reasonably large to get more digits, although things seem to max out between 1000 and 10000 for some reason ...)

```r
library(Rmpfr)
mpfr(a/b, precBits = 1000)
1 'mpfr' number of precision  1000   bits 
[1] 0.03225806451612903225806451612903225806451612903225806
45161290322580645161290322580645161290322580645161290322580
64516129032258064516129032258064516129032258064516129032258
06451612903225806451612903225806451612903225806451612903225
80645161290322580645161290322580645161290322580645161290322
580645161290351
```

Comment: Many thanks. I have used before gmp and Rmpfr but separetely. I understand now that the trick is to use those 2 packages together

Comment: If this answer solved your problem you are encouraged to click on the check-mark to accept it ...